# Underline below selection handle on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

The weird issue I find on Marshmallow is this unwanted underline below selection handles.

I have tried playing with themes and color attributes.

This is just in my application, other apps work fine.

[image]

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code associated with this. AFAIK this isn't a bug with Marshmallow..

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me but I was using drawables for my cursor and selection handle. Putting android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/blue_cursor" in the XML fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I applied Edittext theme as `android:theme` and `style` too. Just removed this from my Edittext:

```
android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355788/5909385