# EditText with custom theme shows underline under selection handle

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme

i am trying to modify the underline color of a EditText by applying a theme.

Style:

```
<style name="MyTheme.EditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_amount"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.EditText"/>
```

Basically it works, but when i try to select or move the cursor the selection handle is also underlined. You can see this in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this style as a

```
<EditText 
   style="@style/MyTheme.EditText"/>
```

Or, you can separate your theme for referencing the editTextStyle attribute.

```
<style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.EditText">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<EditText
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.EditText"/>
```

**Alright, but where are these underlines come from?**

`android:theme` is an attribute of View and when you set a style as `android:theme`, that style will be wrapped by ContextThemeWrapper with context theme while in inflation of view.

So that means, if you set `android:theme` property with style that contains `android:background` item like

```
<item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
```

every child view of this theme owner will be have a green background.

`"Widget.AppCompat.EditText"` is a style and references `?attr/editTextBackground` as a `"android:background"`. And in v21/values-21.xml file `@drawable/abc_edit_text_material` is defined as `editTextBackground`.

So, for your example, `@drawable/abc_edit_text_material` becomes a background of your EditText and SelectionHandlers.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove parent attribute. This is caused only API 23 device.

```
<style name="MyTheme.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

My layout shows a Edittext inside a blue box. There i wanted to have a white text and a white underline and a white selection control.
I've set all in my AppTheme. All fine!

But i also had a Recyclerview blow the blue box. The RecyclerView has white cards that contains Edittext. White text, underline and control makes no sense in white cards. :)

So i tried to change the color of the text, underline and controls to dark gray. But with no success. I had the same issues with the control like in this question.

I tried using the solved answer, but this didn't helped me. 
Maybe my fault, don't know.

So i post here my solution, even the question already answered.

Inside the styles.xml i added:

```
<style name="RecyclerEditText">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkGray</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/darkGray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/darkGray</item>
</style>
```

and in the layout xml i added inside edittext:

```
android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
android:textColorHint="@color/darkGray"
android:theme="@style/RecyclerEditText"
```

--

Now i have no offset in control icon, and no double underline.

Thanks a lot @litmon !
You pushed me to the "remove parent" idea.