# Android Edit Text selection cursor has strange underline

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext, xamarin.android

I have an AppCompatDialogFragment that creates a dialog with a single Edit text. I set the theme of the dialog as well as the Edit Text.

The issue I'm having is the cursor has a strange underline when selecting text. I need to remove this underline. The color of the underline and cursor is controlled by colorControlActivated.

[This demonstrates the issue I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrfZf.png)

The style being applied to the EditText is as follows:

```
 <!--Edit text for Logon dialog-->
  <style name="PrimaryLogonEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/AntartidaRounded-Medium.ttf</item>
  </style>
```

The Edit text layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/TxtInputL_LoginDialogPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtV_LoginDialogMessage"
            local:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            local:errorEnabled="true"
            style="@style/PrimaryColorAppCompatHint"
            local:hintTextAppearance="@style/PrimaryColorAppCompatHint">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtT_LoginDialogPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:text="ValidPassword@1"
                style="@style/PrimaryLogonEditText"
                android:theme="@style/PrimaryLogonEditText"
                local:hintTextAppearance="@style/PrimaryColorAppCompatHint" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think that you can control the selection cursor appearance, but I might mistake

Comment: You can by changing colorControlActivated. The issue is there is a random line underneath the selection cursor as you can see in the picture.

Comment: I have the same issue..did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588019/edittext-with-custom-theme-shows-underline-under-selection-handle/42355788), your EditText takes background from its parent `Widget.AppCompat.EditText`. So, just add this line to your style:

```
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

This will remove the selector cursor's underline.